# select option alternate

Tags: html, html-select

before sorry for my bad english. I describe my problem, therefore, very short.

I click in the first select List on "Gold", the List 3 "Legierung" (999er, 999er, 999er ......)

I Click in the first select List on "**Silber**", the List 3 "Legierung" become **other Words** (333er, 666er .....)

**So the third list is dependent on the selection of the first.**

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/HvmyK/

```
<div class=" goldrechner">

        <div id="calculator">
            <form name=" goldrechner-form" class=" goldrechner-form">
            <input name="pt" value="1650" id="pt" type="hidden">
            <input name="pc" value="100" id="pc" type="hidden">
            <input name="ex" value="1.0048" id="ex" type="hidden">
            <div class=" goldrechner-header">
                <h2>Goldrechner</h2>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>
                <label class="desc" for="gr_em">
                    <span>W&auml;hlen Sie Ihr Edelmetall aus</span>
                                <div>
            <select id="gr_em" name="gr_em" tabindex="1">

<option selected="selected" value="gold">Gold</option>
<option value="silber">Silber</option>
<option value="platin">Platin</option>
<option value="palladium">Palladium</option>


    </select>

            </div>

            <li>

            <label class="desc" for="gc-unit" >
            <span>Gewichtseinheit</span>

            <div>
            <select id="gc-unit" name="gc-unit" tabindex="2">
<option selected="selected" value="gramm">Gramm</option>

    </select>

         </div>

            <li class="colf">
            <label class="desc" for="gr_gewicht" >
            <span>Gewicht</span>
            <div>
            <input id="gr_gewicht" name="gr_gewicht" class="small" tabindex="3" onkeyup="" type="text">

            <li class="colr">
            <label class="desc" for="gc-purity">
            <span>Legierung</span>
                            <div>
            <select id="gc-purity" name="gc-purity" tabindex="4">

<option selected="selected" value=".75">999er</option>
<option value=".917*.725">999er</option>
<option value=".725*.8">999er</option>
<option value=".725*.75">999er</option>
<option value=".725*.585">999er</option>
<option value=".725*.417">999er</option>
<option value=".65*.375">999er</option>
<option value=".65*.333">999er</option>
                    </select>
            </div>

            <li class="worthresult">
                <div class="result">
                    <span class="num">0.00 Euro</span>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: A few links that will help: [1](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent.shtml), [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/working-examples/SCR19/dynselect.html).  For #2, view the source.  The basic technique is to store the data for the options separately (e.g. in a javascript array), and to reset the options for the dynamic select when the control select changes using the `Option` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using jQuery:

All it's currently doing is swapping out the text of each option in the 3rd select element depending on what option is selected in the first select element, but you may also want to make a change to each option's value or ID to be able identify each one individually.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HvmyK/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Monitor first select element for change in selected option
$('select#gr_em').on('change', function(){
    console.log('changed');
    //Change 3rd select text if gold option selection
    if($('option:selected', this).val() === 'gold'){
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(0)').text('Gold - New Option 1');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(1)').text('Gold - New Option 2');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(2)').text('Gold - New Option 3');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(3)').text('Gold - New Option 4');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(4)').text('Gold - New Option 5');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(5)').text('Gold - New Option 6');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(6)').text('Gold - New Option 7');
    }
    //Change 3rd select text if silber option selection
    else if($('option:selected', this).val() === 'silber'){
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(0)').text('Silber - New Option 1');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(1)').text('Silber - New Option 2');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(2)').text('Silber - New Option 3');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(3)').text('Silber - New Option 4');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(4)').text('Silber - New Option 5');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(5)').text('Silber - New Option 6');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(6)').text('Silber - New Option 7');          
    }
    //Change 3rd select text if platin option selection
    else if($('option:selected', this).val() === 'platin'){
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(0)').text('Platin - New Option 1');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(1)').text('Platin - New Option 2');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(2)').text('Platin - New Option 3');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(3)').text('Platin - New Option 4');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(4)').text('Platin - New Option 5');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(5)').text('Platin - New Option 6');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(6)').text('Platin - New Option 7');           
    }
    //Change 3rd select text if palladium option selection 
    else if($('option:selected', this).val() === 'palladium'){
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(0)').text('Palladium - New Option 1');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(1)').text('Palladium - New Option 2');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(2)').text('Palladium - New Option 3');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(3)').text('Palladium - New Option 4');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(4)').text('Palladium - New Option 5');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(5)').text('Palladium - New Option 6');
        $('select#gc-purity option:eq(6)').text('Palladium - New Option 7');        
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This could only work if all the selects had 7 options.  It doesn't even work in the fiddle (the last, 8th option doesn't get replaced).

Comment: @numbers1311407 - Right, the above is just an example to show you how it's possible. He/she can now modify it to work with their own application. user20298089 - Could you please click the check in the top left of the answer to accept the answer - Thanks!